# ionic UI mini fixed sidebar with icons

Tags: user-interface, ionic-framework

Please I need to do something like this picture using ionic
I need to have a menu fixed on all over app screens  with just icons
any HELP!

for now I am using ***"ion-split-pane"*** to create Content 1 and 2 areas
I need to add this blue section beside them

```
<ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="push">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list lines="none">
    
      <ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
        <ion-item [routerLink]="p.url" routerLinkActive="selected" routerDirection="root" 
            detail="false">
          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon + '-outline'"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{p.title}}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list >
  
      <ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false">
        <ion-item routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" routerDirection="root" detail="false">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-in"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            Login
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>

      
    </ion-list>

   
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
```

[image]

Comment: For that Blue Section you can create a custom component and use it on all your pages.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !

I created 3 `<ion-content>`

1 - one for mini sidebar

2 - one for main sidebar (Content area 1).

3- last one is (content area 2) mian content

then created a custom scss for  mini sidebar I gave it a fixed small width